# Python comparison operator precedence

Tags: python, comparison-operators

All comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Thus "==" and "<" have the same priority, why would the first expression in the following evaluate to `True`, different from the 2nd expression?

```
>>> -1 < 0 == False
True

>>> (-1 < 0) == False
False
```

I would expect both be evaluated to `False`. Why is it not the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has a really nice feature - [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), like in math expressions, so

```
-1 < 0 == False
```

is actually a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for

```
-1 < 0 and 0 == False
```

under the hood.

Comment: is it `-1 < 0 and 0 == False` without the "-" before the 2nd "0"?

Comment: Sorry, fixed typo.